# Removing ZIP file containing specific characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When removing a regular folder that contains the characters "ABC" in it, I code this.

```
for /d /r "C:\" %%a in (*ABC*) do rd /s "%%a"
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is deleting not a regular folder but a ZIP file that contains the characters "ABC"

Comment: `del *ABC*.ZIP` - or do you want it recursively?

Comment: `del /S *ABC*.ZIP`

Comment: Can you outline the full code?

Comment: replace `(*ABC*)` with `(*ABC*.ZIP)`, and replace `do rd /s "%%a"` with `del /S %%a`.

Comment: A FOR loop is not needed to accomplish this. Are you still using a FOR loop?

Comment: Yes I'm using a for loop

Comment: I believe that what Alex K and Ken White are suggesting is that you do not need to use a FOR loop. `DEL /S *ABC*.zip` should accomplish the goal.